# Debug Assertion Failed! Invalid Heap Pointer after VS upgrade

Tags: c, visual-c++, malloc, heap-memory, free

We recently upgrade our enterprise app from vs2015 to vs2017.  This entailed quite a bit of upgrades:

Windows SDK to the newest version to 16299
Newest C++ Runtime
2017 debug support
others

We have 3 layers to our application: A C# UI layer, a VC++\CLI middle layer, and a C system layer.

When EITHER of the following happen:
-malloc memory in C layer, free in C++ layer
-malloc in C++, free in C

I get the following debug assertion **(IN RELEASE BUILDS ONLY!)**

[image: Debug assertion failure]

At first we thought we didnt properly upgrade some of the Windows SDK's, but it doesn't seem to be that (after I removed every SDK other than 16299 and it still reproduced).  We did the same thing with debug support and the C++ runtime.

For some reason, it's like the C layer and the C++ layer are now using thier own heap.  This worked before our upgrade, and I cannot figure out what changed.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: When you say the C and C++ layers - are they within the same application?  Also, if you are truly worried, you can overload the memory operators and put a debug shim in there to print who is calling what and going where.  My first thought was this might have something to do with .dll code as dynamic memory access within there can be finicky.

Comment: If you get a crash in release builds only, that's a clear sign that you're doing something you should not, probably something leading to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Typically, crashes that only happens in release builds but not debug builds tend to be because of uninitialized variables. A debug build may cause those to actually *be* initialized, probably as zero which for a pointer means it will be a null pointer. If you check for null pointers it will be caught in the debug build, but not in the release when the value is indeterminate.

Comment: the layer is a C# exe->C++\CLI dll->linked in lib C file.  All in the same application.  We tried (as a test), to just put a simple call to a new method in the C layer (called do_call_free), and if we free the memory there, we're fine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thought the same thing.  The example we're working with is a simple malloc, setting the allocated memory to a string, and returning it.  We're allocating a char* (which we have verified is correct) and then freeing it later in the same method.  

I am assuming there's something wrong in our project configuration somewhere, but that's exactly what i'm posting here for :)

Answer (score 0):

So we figured it out.  There was a mistake in my project files where the Release builds where using the Debug C-runtime-library (the XML node was DebugLibrary, and we where using MultiThreadedDebugDLL instead of MulthThreadedDLL)